# ReAgentc: Unable to update WinRE boot configuration data

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-re

Windows 10 Pro x64 v1909 update fails: 
 Issue seems to be caused by problems with WinRE, receiving the error if I also try to reset the PC.

- I've tried resetting the `ReAgent.xml` [failed] and moving/restoring `winre.wim` to `%WinDir%\system32\Recovery`, then running `reagentc /enabled` [successful], but when I run `/info` again, it shows disabled and the `winre.wim` path is gone.

`ReAgentc /Info`:

- ```powershell
   Windows Recovery Environment (Windows RE) and system reset configuration Information:

   Windows RE status:         Disabled
   Windows RE location:
   Boot Configuration Data (BCD) identifier: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
   Recovery image location:
   Recovery image index:      0
   Custom image location:
   Custom image index:        0
   ReAgentc: Operation Successful.
  ```

`BCDedit /Enum all`:

- ```powershell
   Windows Boot Manager
   --------------------
   identifier              {bootmgr}
   device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
   description             Windows Boot Manager
   default                 {current}
   resumeobject            {0dfb2af9-a292-11e9-ba4c-806e6f6e6963}
   displayorder            {current}
   timeout                 30

   Windows Boot Loader
   -------------------
   identifier              {current}
   device                  partition=C:
   path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
   description             Microsoft Windows 10 x64 Edition
   recoverysequence        {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
   recoveryenabled         Yes
   osdevice                partition=C:
   systemroot              \Windows
   resumeobject            {0dfb2af9-a292-11e9-ba4c-806e6f6e6963}
   nocrashautoreboot       No
   lastknowngood           No

   Resume from Hibernate
   ---------------------
   identifier              {0dfb2af9-a292-11e9-ba4c-806e6f6e6963}
   device                  partition=C:
   path                    \Windows\system32\winresume.exe
   description             Microsoft Windows 10 x64 Edition
   inherit                 {resumeloadersettings}
   recoverysequence        {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
   recoveryenabled         Yes
   filedevice              partition=C:
   filepath                \hiberfil.sys
   debugoptionenabled      No
  ```

`ReAgentc /Enable` logfile:

- ```powershell
   10:37:08, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------
   10:37:08, Info        [ReAgentc] -----Executing command line: reagentc  /?-----
   10:37:08, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------

   10:37:08, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------
   10:37:08, Info        [ReAgentc] -----Exiting command line: reagentc  /?, Error: 0-----
   10:37:08, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------

   10:37:26, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------
   10:37:26, Info        [ReAgentc] -----Executing command line: reagentc  /v-----
   10:37:26, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------

   10:37:26, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------
   10:37:26, Info        [ReAgentc] -----Exiting command line: reagentc  /v, Error: 87-----
   10:37:26, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------

   10:40:00, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------
   10:40:00, Info        [ReAgentc] -----Executing command line: reagentc  /info-----
   10:40:00, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------
   10:40:00, Info        [ReAgentc] Enter WinReGetConfig
   10:40:00, Info        [ReAgentc] Parameters: configWinDir: NULL
   10:40:00, Info        [ReAgentc] WinRE config file path: C:\Windows\system32\Recovery\ReAgent.xml
   10:40:00, Info        [ReAgentc] Update enhanced config info is enabled.
   10:40:00, Error       [ReAgentc] BcdOpenObject(WinRE) failed: 0xc0000034
   10:40:00, Info        [ReAgentc] winreGetWinReGuid returning 0X2
   10:40:00, Info        [ReAgentc] ReAgentConfig::ReadBcdAndUpdateEnhancedConfigInfo WinRE disabled, WinRE Guid could not be determined  (0x2) 
   10:40:00, Info        [ReAgentc] WinRE is staged
   10:40:00, Info        [ReAgentc] System is WimBoot: FALSE
   10:40:00, Info        [ReAgentc] Exit WinReGetConfig return value: 1, last error: 0x0

   10:40:00, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------
   10:40:00, Info        [ReAgentc] -----Exiting command line: reagentc  /info, Error: 0-----
   10:40:00, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------

   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] -----Executing command line: reagentc  /enable-----
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] Enter WinRECheckGuid
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] Parameter: TargetOsGuid: : NULL 
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] Exit WinRECheckGuid return error code: 0x0
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] Enter WinReInstall
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] Parameter: ReInstallBecauseOfBitlocker: 0

   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] --Install on target OS step 1: collect info like partition list, loading reagent.xml, source winre.wim and partition
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] Enumerate and log all fixed partitions:

   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] --Partition info--
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] VolumeName: \\?\Volume{55abc128-0000-0000-0000-602200000000}, PartitionName: \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition2
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] Partition number: 2, offset: 576716800, free space: 299773304832, total space: 511531372544
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] DiskNumber:0, DiskSignature:1437319464, NTFS:1, Mbr:1, Active:0, Boot:1, BitlockerEnabled:0
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] MBR partition id: 0x7
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] DiskId: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} 
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] --Partition info--
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] VolumeName: \\?\Volume{55abc128-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}, PartitionName: \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition1
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] Partition number: 1, offset: 1048576, free space: 541589504, total space: 575664128
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] DiskNumber:0, DiskSignature:1437319464, NTFS:1, Mbr:1, Active:1, Boot:0, BitlockerEnabled:0
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] MBR partition id: 0x7
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] DiskId: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} 
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] Get downlevel ReAgent config
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc]  Downlevel config file path: \Recovery\ReAgentOld.xml
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc]  Checking for downlevel WinRE installation.
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] First round search
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] Get ReAgent config
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] GetReAgentConfig Config file path: C:\Windows\system32\Recovery\ReAgent.xml
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] CheckRegKey test hook (SystemSetupInProgress) present and disabled
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] Update enhanced config info is enabled.
   10:40:05, Error       [ReAgentc] BcdOpenObject(WinRE) failed: 0xc0000034
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] winreGetWinReGuid returning 0X2
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] ReAgentConfig::ReadBcdAndUpdateEnhancedConfigInfo WinRE disabled, WinRE Guid could not be determined  (0x2) 
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] --Install on target OS step 2: detect and fix if there is any issue for winre settings
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] DetectAndFixWinReIssues (WinRE)WinRE is already installed, setting BCD entry (winre location \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition2\Recovery\WindowsRE)
   10:40:05, Error       [ReAgentc] BcdOpenObject(WinRE) failed: 0xc0000034
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] winreGetWinReGuid returning 0X2
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] DetectAndFixWinReIssues Failed to get WinRE GUID.
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] DetectAndFixWinReIssues Will fix the BCD entry.
   10:40:05, Error       [ReAgentc] BcdOpenObject(WinRE) failed: 0xc0000034
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] winreGetWinReGuid returning 0X2
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] NOTE: WILL RETRY. We have to uninstall WinRE and retry because WinRE is installed but its BCD entry is not present.
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] DetectAndFixWinReIssues Copying Winre.wim from \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition2\Recovery\WindowsRE to staging location
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] winreCopyWIMBack moved WIM file from \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition2\Recovery\WindowsRE\ to C:\Windows\system32\Recovery\Winre.wim successfully!
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] DetectAndFixWinReIssues we should retry because winre installation was changed.
   10:40:05, Error       [ReAgentc] failed to detect and fix winre issues, error:0x2
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] Exit WinReInstall return value: 0, last error: 0x2
   10:40:05, Error       [ReAgentc] failed to install winre: : 0x2

   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] -----Exiting command line: reagentc  /enable, Error: 2-----
   10:40:05, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------

   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] -----Executing command line: reagentc  /enable-----
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Enter WinRECheckGuid
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Parameter: TargetOsGuid: : NULL
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Exit WinRECheckGuid return error code: 0x0
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Enter WinReInstall
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Parameter: ReInstallBecauseOfBitlocker: 0

   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] --Install on target OS step 1: collect info like partition list, loading reagent.xml, source winre.wim and partition
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Enumerate and log all fixed partitions:

   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] --Partition info--
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] VolumeName: \\?\Volume{55abc128-0000-0000-0000-602200000000}, PartitionName: \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition2
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Partition number: 2, offset: 576716800, free space: 300220190720, total space: 511531372544
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] DiskNumber:0, DiskSignature:1437319464, NTFS:1, Mbr:1, Active:0, Boot:1, BitlockerEnabled:0
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] MBR partition id: 0x7
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] DiskId: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] --Partition info--
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] VolumeName: \\?\Volume{55abc128-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}, PartitionName: \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition1
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Partition number: 1, offset: 1048576, free space: 541589504, total space: 575664128
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] DiskNumber:0, DiskSignature:1437319464, NTFS:1, Mbr:1, Active:1, Boot:0, BitlockerEnabled:0
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] MBR partition id: 0x7
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] DiskId: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} 
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Get downlevel ReAgent config
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc]  Downlevel config file path: \Recovery\ReAgentOld.xml
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc]  Checking for downlevel WinRE installation.
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] First round search
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Get ReAgent config
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] GetReAgentConfig Config file path: C:\Windows\system32\Recovery\ReAgent.xml
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] CheckRegKey test hook (SystemSetupInProgress) present and disabled
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Update enhanced config info is enabled.
   10:40:08, Error       [ReAgentc] BcdOpenObject(WinRE) failed: 0xc0000034
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] winreGetWinReGuid returning 0X2
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] ReAgentConfig::ReadBcdAndUpdateEnhancedConfigInfo WinRE disabled, WinRE Guid could not be determined  (0x2)
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] FindWinReSourceImageAndPartition No source winre.wim was specified.  Checking for a staged winre.wim.
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] FindWinReSourceImageAndPartition using winre.wim from C:\Windows\system32\Recovery

   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] --Install on target OS step 2: detect and fix if there is any issue for winre settings
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] DetectAndFixWinReIssues nothing to do because winre is not enabled.

   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] --Install on target OS step 3: check if we can keep winre.wim in the same partition if it is staged.

   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] --Install on target OS step 4: check if we can put winre.wim in other partitions or create one if needed.

   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] CanPutWinREOnOtherPartitions WinRE is not staged. Searching for a suitable partition for WinRE.
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Entering FindTargetPartition
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] RegLoadKey $OFFLINE$SYSTEM failed. Error: 0x522.
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc]  Not allowed to repartition the disk
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Start looping through each partition and initialize os partition, recovery partition and system partition for MBR
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc]  Checking partition at offset 576716800, partition number: 2
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc]  find OS partition
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc]  Checking partition at offset 1048576, partition number: 1
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc]  NOTE: find system partition and not OS partition for MBR
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Complete looping through each partition

   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] ----Search target partition option #1: try existing WinRE partition

   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] ----Search target partition option #2: try first recovery partition

   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] ----Search target partition option #3: try system partition for MBR

   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] MeetPartitionRequirements Partition details: {Offset: 1048576, Free space: 541589504, Total space: 575664128}
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] MeetPartitionRequirements WinRE WIM size: 443717121
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] MeetPartitionRequirements Required free space: 831690241
   10:40:08, Warning     [ReAgentc] MeetPartitionRequirements Not enough free space req = 831690241 avail = 541589504 offset = 1048576

   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] ----Search target partition option #4: try new recovery partition if allowed

   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] ----Search target partition option #5: try target OS partition

   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] MeetPartitionRequirements Partition details: {Offset: 576716800, Free space: 300220190720, Total space: 511531372544}
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] MeetPartitionRequirements WinRE WIM size: 443717121
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] MeetPartitionRequirements Required free space: 52428800
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Found target partition: use target OS partition, offset: 576716800
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Exit FindTargetPartition returns with status code: 0x0

   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] --Install on target OS step 5: set WinRE settings and restore system to a good state when hitting any errors
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Enter SetWinRESettings
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] RegLoadKey $OFFLINE$SYSTEM failed. Error: 0x522.
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Copying WinRE from C:\Windows\system32\Recovery to staging location on \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition2
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] RegLoadKey $OFFLINE$SYSTEM failed. Error: 0x522.
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Copied WinRE to staging location
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Creating BCD entry
   10:40:08, Error       [ReAgentc] BcdGetElementData failed: 0xc0000225
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] WinRE created BCD entry: : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} 
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Moving Winre and boot.sdi from staging location to target
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Moved Winre and boot.sdi from staging location to target
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Updating reagent.xml
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Set WinRE location path to: \Recovery\WindowsRE
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Set recovery guid
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Set scheduled operation: WinReNoOperation
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Set OS build version: 17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Set Wimboot state: 0
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Set install state to: enabled
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Setting the recovery sequence for the target OS.
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Machine firmware is not EFI, nothing to do
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Creating backup of reagent.xml
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Created backup of reagent.xml
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Configuring the WinRE validation task.
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Failed to clear WIM file trusted state: 0x2
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Failed to clear WIM file hash: 0x2
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Update enhanced config info is enabled.
   10:40:08, Error       [ReAgentc] BcdOpenObject(WinRE) failed: 0xc0000034
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] winreGetWinReGuid returning 0X2
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] ReAgentConfig::ReadBcdAndUpdateEnhancedConfigInfo WinRE disabled, WinRE Guid could not be determined  (0x2) 
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Failed to find winre.wim because WinRE is not installed.
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] WinReValidateRecoveryWimInternal took 16 ms.
   10:40:08, Warning     [ReAgentc] WinReValidateRecoveryWimInternal failed: 0x490
   10:40:08, Warning     [ReAgentc] winreConfigureValidationTask failed: 0x490, a non critical error
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Completed the WinRE validation task.
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Creating backup of customization file
   10:40:08, Warning     [ReAgentc] Recovery file not found at C:\Windows\system32\Recovery\ReCustomization.xml
   10:40:08, Warning     [ReAgentc] winreBackupRecoveryFile (C:\Windows\system32\Recovery\ReCustomization.xml, ReCustomization.xml) failed, Err: 2
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Created backup of customization file
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] SetWinRESettings return with error code 0x0
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] WinReInstallOnTargetOSInternal WinRE installation completed successfully.
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Exit WinReInstall return value: 1, last error: 0x0
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Enter WinReSetConfig
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Parameters: configWinDir: NULL
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Update enhanced config info is enabled.
   10:40:08, Error       [ReAgentc] BcdOpenObject(WinRE) failed: 0xc0000034
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] winreGetWinReGuid returning 0X2
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] ReAgentConfig::ReadBcdAndUpdateEnhancedConfigInfo WinRE disabled, WinRE Guid could not be determined  (0x2) 
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] WinRE is not installed, nothing to back up
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Exit WinReSetConfig return value: 1, last error: 0x0
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] Clear non critical error when enabling auto repair

   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] -----Exiting command line: reagentc  /enable, Error: 0-----
   10:40:08, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------

   10:42:05, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------
   10:42:05, Info        [ReAgentc] -----Executing command line: reagentc  /info-----
   10:42:05, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------
   10:42:05, Info        [ReAgentc] Enter WinReGetConfig
   10:42:05, Info        [ReAgentc] Parameters: configWinDir: NULL
   10:42:05, Info        [ReAgentc] WinRE config file path: C:\Windows\system32\Recovery\ReAgent.xml
   10:42:05, Info        [ReAgentc] Update enhanced config info is enabled.
   10:42:05, Error       [ReAgentc] BcdOpenObject(WinRE) failed: 0xc0000034
   10:42:05, Info        [ReAgentc] winreGetWinReGuid returning 0X2
   10:42:05, Info        [ReAgentc] ReAgentConfig::ReadBcdAndUpdateEnhancedConfigInfo WinRE disabled, WinRE Guid could not be determined  (0x2) 
   10:42:05, Info        [ReAgentc] System is WimBoot: FALSE
   10:42:05, Info        [ReAgentc] Exit WinReGetConfig return value: 1, last error: 0x0

   10:42:05, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------
   10:42:05, Info        [ReAgentc] -----Exiting command line: reagentc  /info, Error: 0-----
   10:42:05, Info        [ReAgentc] ------------------------------------------------------
  ```

Comment: Can you generate the reagentc logfile when you do the enable and post it

Comment: Did you try reagentc /enable and reboot?

Comment: If you cannot enable it then fix the boot record and try again>>>>>https://www.kapilarya.com/fix-windows-10-master-boot-record-corrupted

Comment: Moab - I did, and same result

Comment: Moab - the boot record is not corrupted since i can run bcdedit /enum without problem...see original port for output of bcdedit /enum all

Comment: I also got `BcdOpenObject(WinRE) failed: 0xc0000034` while trying to `reagentc /enable` after `reagentc /setreimage …`. Mine is a UEFI system with a GPT disk, and I'll bet that yours is too.

Comment: Nope, Legacy/MBR in my case.

Answer (score 8):

The solution is to use `/OSguid` for the Windows Boot Loader with Windows Boot Manager, not the Windows Recovery Environment or Windows Resume Application:

```powershell
ReAgentc /Enable /OSguid {GUID}
```

- Your GUID is listed as `{current}`, so run the following, which will give you the GUID, and you should be fine to enable it:

  ```powershell
  BCDedit /V /Enum all
  ```

Comment: What GUID from BCDEDIT output to use? There are many of these, which one from what section, precisely?

Comment: The GUID corresponding to the {current} one when not using the Verbose option or perhaps the GUID corresponding to the "default" entry in the Windows Boot Manager.  It really depends why you have multiple entries (stale, dual boot, recovery, etc) so there is no simple answer for complicated cases.  For "normal" cases likely what I just mentioned should be enough.

Comment: Then you shouldn't write {current} like it's an entry labeled exactly this way.

Comment: @GregoryMorse  The only time `/OSguid` would be used is from within WinPE [only](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/reagentc-command-line-options#reagentc-commands) _(when booted to Windows, `ReAgentC` by default applies WinRE to the current OS GUID)_. The OP's issue is as a result of specifying the incorrect location for the `WinRE.wim`, as the default location on Windows 10 is `\\WinRE_partition\Recovery\WindowsRE` if UEFI; if BIOS, **and** it was an upgrade _(or any OS <Win10)_, it would be `C:\Recovery\WindowsRE`.

Answer (score 7):

---

*WinRE should not be stored on the system partition or the boot partition [BIOS], as it prevents booting to recovery should an issue with either partition occur*

---

The default [`winre.wim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference) location is **NOT** `%WinDir%\system32\Recovery`:

- **BIOS:** *(WinRE should be on it's own partition - **only** Windows 10 clean installs do so)*

  - **Windows ≥10:** `\\WinRE_partition\Recovery\WindowsRE` 
     *(Upgrade: `C:\Recovery\WindowsRE`)*
  - **Windows  ≤8.1:** `C:\Recovery\WindowsRE`
- **UEFI:** `\\WinRE_partition\Recovery\WindowsRE`

**To Resolve, either #2 or #3:** ([`ReAgentc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/reagentc-command-line-options))

1. **Open an *Admin* Terminal:** **<kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>** → *Open*: `powershell` → **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>**+*OK*
2. **Ensure `winre.wim` is within `C:\Recovery\WindowsRE` and set correct path:**

   ```powershell
   ReAgentc /Disable ; ReAgentC /SetREimage /Path "C:\Recovery\WindowsRE" ; ReAgentc /Enable ; ReAgentc /Info
   ```

   ***-- OR --***
3. **Move WinRE to its own partition:**

   1. **Backup current `winre.wim`:**

      1. Verify if `C:\Windows\System32\Recovery\WinRE.wim` exists:

         ```powershell
         Ls "C:\Windows\System32\Recovery" | FindStr /I "WinRE.wim" ; ls "C:\Windows\System32\Recovery" -Hidden | FindStr /I "WinRE.wim"
         ```
      2. If it doesn't:

         ```powershell
         Xcopy /H "C:\Recovery\WindowsRE\WinRE.wim" "C:\Windows\System32\Recovery"
         ```

         - BIOS: *May store WinRE on Boot partition: Mount Boot at `Y:` → Update WIM path*
   2. **Create a 650MB WinRE partition:** **<kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>** → *Open*: [**`DiskPart`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart) → OK

      ```powershell
      ::# WinRE partition should have ~300MB free for future winre.wim size increases

      ::# Select OS partition: 
      sel vol c

      ::# Shrink partition by 665MB [RAW]:
      shrink desired=665 minimum=650

      ::# Create WinRE partition:

        ::# BIOS:
        cre par pri size=665 id=27

        ::# UEFI:
        cre par pri size=665 id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
        gpt attributes=0x8000000000000001

      ::# Format partition:
      format fs=ntfs quick label=WinRE

      ::# Mount partition:
      assign letter=z

      exit
      ```
   3. **Disable WinRE, set custom location of `winre.wim`, and re-enable WinRE:**

      ```powershell
      # Copy WinRE.wim:
        MkDir "Z:\Recovery\WindowsRE" ; Xcopy /H "C:\Recovery\WindowsRE\WinRE.wim" "Z:\Recovery\WindowsRE"

      # Disable WinRE:
        ReAgentC /Disable

      # Set Custom WinRE Path:
        ReAgentC /SetREimage /Path "Z:\Recovery\WindowsRE"

      # Enable WinRE:
        ReAgentC /Enable

      # Verify:
        ReAgentC /Info

      # Remove WinRE mount point:
        DiskPart
          sel vol z
          remove
          exit
      ```

---

To address a factually inaccurate misunderstanding that resulted in a downvote:

- This answer, nor the OP's question, has anything to do with the [BCD store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/boot-options-in-windows#boot-configuration-data): 
   OP's issue is the default `winre.wim` location is not `%WinDir%\system32\Recovery`

Comment: Hi I am having a similar issue. And I have a dual booted system. Does this also apply to it. As it's setup my Windows 10 dual boot is on the same SSD along with my System boot partition @JW0914

Comment: @edo101 Yes, it applies to all Windows installs that use a [BCD Store](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcd-system-store-settings-for-uefi) for booting.

Comment: Yes, we know this, but this won't solve the BCD problem.

Comment: i followed your recipe but did not work later when enabling  (i could not remember the error message). later found this more precise command which worked on my win10:

reagentc /setreimage /path Z:\Recovery\WindowsRE /target C:\Windows

Comment: @Max The [`/target`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/reagentc-command-line-options?view=windows-11#setreimage-syntax)  option is only used when enabling WinRE on an install not currently booted to _(e.g. if you were booted to WinPE/WinRE, `/target` would need to be specified, but not if you're booted to the same OS its being enabled on)_. Without logs, troubleshooting isn't possible, but if you run into the issue again, please copy all terminal content, as well as any log output to [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/) and share the link =]